# Ansible expect get strange symbols

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate some activities using Ansible module expect. When I do it manually I see the next output:

```
ssh admin@ip
hpiLO-> textcons
HAV login:
```

But what I see in ansible logs:

```
<-[0m<-1m[0m<-1m<-2J<-[H<-[3;28H<-[1;1H<-[0;25;37;40
<-[2;1H<-[0;25;37;40mHAV login:^[
```

And a lot of such symbols. And my playbook fails of-course:

```
expect:
  command: ssh admin@ip
  responses:
    password: <password>
    hpiLO-> textcons
    login: <login> - here it stops
    Password: <Password>
    \]# touch test.txt
```

Any ideas what are these symbols ?

Comment: could it be color code for the console ?

Comment: This is what I am trying to ask))

Comment: `responses` is suppose to be a dictionary with expected strings/regexes as keys and strings to send back as values (i.e. `"expected response or regex": "value to send back"` on each line). The lines `hpiLO-> textcons` and `\]# touch test.txt` are not valid yaml in this context. I'm even surprised this gets executed at all without ansible yelling out an error. Can you fix, retry and see it correct the issue?

Comment: Why hpiiLO-> textcons is incorrect?

Comment: Please [take y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) then read the [`response` parameter description in `expect` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#parameter-responses), then re-read my above comment and you will be able to answer your own question <= **it is not a valid yaml dictionnary entry.**